# SAS: do loop attribute selection dynamically

Tags: sas

i have a data set with multiple attributes and each attribute has 10-15 rows each in the master table. i wish to use a do loop on the data set which would allow me to extract outputs for each attribute seperately. my concern is how to automate the selection of attribute in the do loop once the previous attribute's output is extracted??

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this would be easier to answer if you provided some sample data, both before and after.  Your question isn't that clear at the moment

Comment: What do you mean by multiple attributes? Is that multiple variables? The mention of the master table is confusing. Perhaps a data example will help.

Comment: Are you intending to get separate datasets for each attribute?  Why?  What is your ultimate goal?  Why do you say "do loop" - odds are a do loop isn't needed, is it a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking to do, but I can hopefully show the basic ideas of a do loop.

```
%macro YOUR_MACRO();
   %let YOUR_VARIABLE = 1 2 3 ...;  /*This could be whatever you want to split up from your master table*/
   %let NUM_VAR = 3; /*Change this to the number of YOUR_VARIABLEs listed*/

   %do i = 1 %to &NUM_VAR. %by 1;
       %let LOOP_VAR = %scan(&YOUR_VARIABLE., %i.);
/*This do i = 1 starts your loop at 1 and goes up by 1 until your NUM_VAR is reached*/

proc sql;
    create table TABLE_&LOOP_VAR. as /*Creates a specific table for each variable*/
    select *
    from MASTER_TABLE
    where COLUMN_NAME = &LOOP_VAR. /*Splits up your table by a certain attribute equaling the loop variable*/
    ;
quit;

%end;
%mend;
%YOUR_MACRO(); /*Runs your loop*/
```

This is the basic structure and should give a little help. You can also just scan your master table for each variable name then separate it by that without having to type each one out.